# Bot Framework - imBack or postBack message without buttons? Is it possible?

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I am trying to display a card (or list of links ) to my Skype, Slack or Messenger users with some postBack actions.

Herocard works fine, they display the buttons with the text like in this example:

```
    IMessageActivity replyMessage = context.MakeMessage();
    replyMessage.Attachments.Add(
    new HeroCard
    {
        Subtitle = "Settings",
        Buttons = new List<CardAction> {
            new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, $"Spell-check {spellcheckst}", value: $"Set Spell-check setting {spellcheckst}", text: $"Spell-check {spellcheckst}", displayText: $"Spell-check {spellcheckst}"),
            new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, $"Small-talk {smalltalkst}", value: $"Set Small-talk setting {smalltalkst}", text: $"Small-talk {smalltalkst}", displayText: $"Small-talk {smalltalkst}")

        }
    }.ToAttachment()
    );
    await context.PostAsync(replyMessage);
```

But buttons take a lot of screen real estate and many times their captions are truncated.

Is there a way to trigger a postBack or imBack card action without displaying buttons. Here is an example scenario, when the User asks for Help, the Bot displays list of commands:

1. Add a webpage [Try Me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688102/bot-framework-imback-or-postback-message-without-buttons-is-it-possible)
2. delete a webpage [Try Me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688102/bot-framework-imback-or-postback-message-without-buttons-is-it-possible)
3. Display help [Try Me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688102/bot-framework-imback-or-postback-message-without-buttons-is-it-possible)
4. etc.

The "Try Me" links would postBack to the bot exactly as the buttons above do.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, large button name will create a problem and it's look like alien to cards. In place of that you can do that using Carousel Cards. Put below code in your dialog and check. I am doing it and its working.

```
 public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
        {
            var reply = context.MakeMessage();

            reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
            reply.Attachments = GetCardsAttachments();

            await context.PostAsync(reply);

            context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
        }

        private static IList<Attachment> GetCardsAttachments()
        {
            return new List<Attachment>()
            {
                GetHeroCard(
                    "Add a webpage",
                    "",
                    "",
                    new CardImage(url: "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/22691/screenshots/1958250/attachments/340010/Button_800x600.gif?sz=328"),
                    new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "Add a webpage", value: "Add a webpage")),
                GetHeroCard(
                    "delete a webpage",
                    "",
                    "",
                    new CardImage(url: "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/22691/screenshots/1958250/attachments/340010/Button_800x600.gif?sz=328"),
                    new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "delete a webpage", value: "delete a webpage")),
                GetHeroCard(
                    "Display help",
                    "",
                    "",
                    new CardImage(url: "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/22691/screenshots/1958250/attachments/340010/Button_800x600.gif?sz=328"),
                    new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "Display help", value: "Display help")),
                GetHeroCard(
                    "etc",
                    "",
                    "",
                    new CardImage(url: "https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/22691/screenshots/1958250/attachments/340010/Button_800x600.gif?sz=328"),
                    new CardAction(ActionTypes.ImBack, "etc", value: "etc")),

            };
        }

        private static Attachment GetHeroCard(string title, string subtitle, string text, CardImage cardImage, CardAction cardAction)
        {
            var heroCard = new HeroCard
            {
                Title = title,
                Subtitle = subtitle,
                Text = text,
                Images = new List<CardImage>() { cardImage },
                Buttons = new List<CardAction>() { cardAction },
            };

            return heroCard.ToAttachment();
        }
```

I hope this will help you out to solve your concern.

Below is the scren shot for your reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the buttons, you can set the title to the display text, and set the value to what you need to post back. Then you could have a little piece of text above the buttons that says something along the lines, "click any of the buttons to try".

I use this approach within messenger, to make my button text short, but the "payload" (or value) of the button set to a richer description. Next thing is, the value is not displayed to the user, but it is received by the framework within the channel data portion of the message activity.